What does "hovering" mean here?
Spot swings through Mumbattan, feeling amazed by his changes, unsure if he'd recognize
himself in the mirror. Gwen tells him to stop, but Spot admires the person he's become,
hinting at thinking about who he really is:

GWEN (to Jess): I’ve got eyes on the anomaly.
JESS : Try getting hands on him.
Gwen (to Jess): Stop hovering. You're literally hovering.

What does "hovering" mean here?

Seems like you're asking an English language question? There's another stackexchange for this.

Agreed, [ell.se] would be a better place to ask this kind of question.

@AndresF. - Questions about word-meaning in Science Fiction or Fantasy is perfectly well on topic.

@Valorum I'm not arguing it's off-topic, just that there are better sites for this kind of questions (+1 to your answer, by the way).

In this context 'hovering' has two meanings,
Meaning 1:

(of a person) to wait somewhere, especially near someone, in a shy or uncertain manner.
Oxford Learners Dictionary

Gwen is concerned that Jess is trying to micro-manage her fight with Spot, telling her what to do and potentially interfering with her instinctual decision-making process. She accuses her of looking over Gwen's shoulder when she could, presumably, be more usefully occupied elsewhere (or just leave her alone to get on with her job).
Meaning 2

(of birds, helicopters, etc.) to stay in the air in one place

Gwen notes that she is also 'literally hovering', that is to say that Jess is currently appearing in the form of a hologrammatic projection emanating from Gwen's wrist gizmo. Jess is quite literally floating in front of Gwen right in the middle of a fight and being quite the distraction. Not helping, hindering.
